# Good data set for Pre-processing

Tags: preprocessor, machine-learning, data-mining

I am enrolled in an under-graduate course in Data Mining and I've got an assignment to code a Data Mining Pre-processor. I have the liberty to choose the programming language and the data set. I was wondering if anybody could suggest a good data set to use. I have been going through the [UCI Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.html) and I've found many more such resources. But being a beginner I am not sure which data set would be a good choice. The preprocessor should be dealing with the following stuff:

- Data cleaning

  - Missing Values
  - Errors
  - Outliers
  - Nomralization
  - De-duplication
- Data Reduction

  - Sampling Techniques
  - Dimensionality Reduction

What kind of properties should I consider when choosing the data set? Any specific data set you would suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question. Choose list of data-set with the properties that you have mentioned as UCI repository has categorized dataset. You can chose anyone to start playing with it.

So to start with, if I were you,I would proceed step wise, have a feel how each of those look like and its effect  on  classifier performance and choose some of the **popular dataset** as they are used as benchmark dataset in most of the research paper. Much of those that you have listed are separate machine learning problems with lots of researches being conducted.

I would start with something like this :
for missing values :  *Iris, Voting,Heart disease* 
for Duplicate:*921,810 song dataset(not form UCI I think)*  
Normalization : Any continuous valued dataset with different range for features  
Sampling technique : *Pima* 
Dimensionality reduction : *Swiss Roll*

Further, another best approach to look for the data set would be to refer some of respective publications. Such as , for dimensionality reduction, you can look into papers of *PCA, ISOMAP* etc, for sampling see *SMOTE* paper etc and see what type of data do they use for their experiments and proceed accordingly.

Comment: I was wondering if i could find a single dataset that would work for all those, but that was a long shot anyway. Thanks a lot for the suggestions, will go through them.